# Checkout previous commit and attach HEAD to it

Tags: git

I have such git log:

```
13491f7d70b6f5b287d2029ab2ce208c32d4e38e (HEAD -> OPO-2797) [OPO-2797], fixes according to codereview
6981280f1724a009e9cd7eb4306c201af772b8fc (origin/OPO-2797) [OPO-2797], merge data from QWE_LK3 and ELS_ERS
```

I would like to checkout to `6981280f1` and make it the HEAD of the OPO-2797 branch. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already on the OPO-2797 branch, so you just need to reset.  Just do:

```
git reset 6981280f1724a009
```

It sounds like you also want to modify your working directory,  in which case you need:

```
git reset --hard 6981280f1724a009 # Warning: don't do this if you have uncommitted changes you want to keep
```

Note that 'reset --hard' will discard any changes in your working directory, so don't do that if your working directory is dirty (eg, you have unstaged changes.)  It will *not* discard commit 13491f7d70b6f5b28, but may make it unreachable and subject to subsequent garbage collection.  If you want to keep it, tag it or make a new branch.